# XSLT: Wrap every 3rd div in a div

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'm looking to get some XSLT (for Umbraco CMS) coded properly and I'm getting kind of stumped. What I'm trying to do is:

**Start from a certain node, put each child node into a div; for every 3 children, wrap in a parent div.**

Instead of my mess of `for-each`,`choose` and `when` statements, I have tried implementing a `apply-template` structure but I just can't seem to get the hang of it; so here's my mess of XSLT right now (I'm sure this is bad practice & terrible for performance, but I really don't know what to do at the moment):

```
<div class="row four">
<h2>Smart Phones <a href="#" class="see-all">see all smart phones &rarr;</a></h2>
<div class="row three"> <!-- This div should be created again for every 3 divs -->
        <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById('1063')/descendant::*[@isDoc and string(showInMainNavigation) = '1']">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() &lt; 3">
                    <div class="col">
                        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(./@id)}">
                            <img class="phonePreviewImg" src="{./previewImage}" style="max-width:117px; max-height:179px;" />
                            <h4 class="phoneTitle"><xsl:value-of select="./@nodeName" />/h4>
                            <p class="phonePrice">$<xsl:value-of select="./price" /></p
                        </a>
                     </div>
                 </xsl:when>

                 <xsl:when test="position() = 3"> <!-- set this div to include class of `omega` -->
                    <div class="col omega">
                        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(./@id)}">
                            <img class="phonePreviewImg" src="{./previewImage}" style="max-width:117px; max-height:179px;" />
                            <h4 class="phoneTitle"><xsl:value-of select="./@nodeName" />/h4>
                            <p class="phonePrice">$<xsl:value-of select="./price" /></p
                        </a>
                     </div>
                 </xsl:when>                                                                                
             </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:for-each>
     </div> <!-- End Row Three -->
</div> <!-- End Row Four -->
```

Obviously this code does not produce the "wrap every three". Can anyone shed some light on what I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - improved the answer

I cannot think of an elegant solution using templates, but this clunky one with a loop works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template name="render">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:param name="last"/>
    <div>
      <xsl:if test="$last">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:text>omega</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$node"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="*[not(@skip)]"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 3)=1">
          <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
          <div>
            <xsl:call-template name="render">
              <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
              <xsl:with-param name="last" select="false()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:if test="$nodes[$position+1]">
              <xsl:call-template name="render">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$nodes[$position+1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="last" select="false()"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$nodes[$position+2]">
              <xsl:call-template name="render">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$nodes[$position+2]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="last" select="true()"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to:

```
<root>
  <node>1</node>
  <node skip="1">to be skipped</node>
  <node>2</node>
  <node>3</node>
  <node skip="1">to be skipped</node>
  <node skip="1">to be skipped</node>
  <node>4</node>
  <node skip="1">to be skipped</node>
  <node>5</node>
  <node>6</node>
  <node>7</node>
  <node skip="1">to be skipped</node>
</root>
```

produces:

```
<root>
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="omega">3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div class="omega">6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
</root>
```

You need to replace the `select` used to set the `$nodes` variable the XPath selecting the nodes you want, and the `render` template with the code needed to generate the result you need for each node.

Answer (score 1):

**As simple and short as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="num[position() mod 3 = 1]">
   <div>
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"
         select=".|following-sibling::*[not(position() >2)]"/>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="inGroup">
  <p><xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"/></p>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<div>
   <p>01</p>
   <p>02</p>
   <p>03</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>04</p>
   <p>05</p>
   <p>06</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>07</p>
   <p>08</p>
   <p>09</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>10</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I implement this? I need this code to be dropped into a certain spot in a larger XSL document (inside a choose > when statement). I tried doing `<xsl:call-template />` with no luck.

Comment: @motoxer4533, Good XSLT code doesn't have any conditional instructions (`xsl:choose`, `xsl:when`, `xsl:otherwise`, `xsl:if`) or `xsl:call-template` or `xsl:for-each` instructions. It is in the spirit of XSLT to use templates and match patterns instead. If you don't know how to integrate a working solution into your code, then please, read a good book on XSLT.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; unfortunately the time it would take to "read a good XSLT book" is not a luxury I have at the moment.

Comment: @motoxer4533, This time is necessary and there is no replacement for it -- I think it was Lomonossov who told the Russian tzar: "There is no "tzar way" into science" :) I would strongly recommend having a solid introduction into XSLT, or not using XSLT at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elegant solution using templates.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:param name="pNumInGroup" select="3" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() mod $pNumInGroup = 1]" />
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node">
     <div>
        <xsl:for-each
          select=".|following-sibling::*[not(position() &gt; $pNumInGroup - 1)]">
          <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each> 
     </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the sample XML provided by @MiMo:**

```
<root>
  <node>1</node>
  <node>2</node>
  <node>3</node>
  <node>4</node>
  <node>5</node>
  <node>6</node>
  <node>7</node>
</root>
```

**...the correct result is produced:**

```
<html>
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

**If the parameter value is changed to `5`:**

```
<xsl:param name="pNumInGroup" select="5" />
```

**...the correct result is still produced:**

```
<html>
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

**Explanation:**

- We define a `pNumInGroup` parameter at the top of the document (with a default value of `3`). This is useful, as it allows the XSLT to be used more flexibly (i.e., if you need a different number of `<div>` elements per group, simply pass them as a parameter).
- The first template matches the root node, recreates it, and tells the XSLT processor to apply templates to the first element of each grouping ([here's a refresher in modular  arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) in case you need it).
- The second template matches the `<node>` elements that are selected by the previous template. For each, a new `<div>` element is created and populated with the remaining items appropriate to that wrapped group.

**NOTE:** I generally stay away from `<xsl:for-each>` unless I *really* need it; in the case of the last template, I don't really need it (I could just as easily have specified the wrapping/secondary `<div>` logic with another template). However, for the sake of "crispness" and not over-templating the XSLT, I chose this route.